# How to keep track of subclasses of my cython extension type?

Tags: python, cython, metaclass

I've been using Cython for the last few years to speedup certain parts of my python code (mostly related to heavy scientific calculations inside large loops). This week I came across something completely new: How can I keep track of the subclasses that extend my extension type? In pure python, this is a pretty straightforward task performed with metaclasses. But since metaclass is not supported for extension types in cython, how am I supposed to run some code everytime my extension type is extended?

I've googled the question and found no result whatsoever.

Comment: Would it be viable to wrap the cython class with a pure-Python class that does use a metaclass?

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted it because it was wrong - if you saw it please ignore it!

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while, but I think that I just figure that out. It turns out that one doesn't really need metaclasses to run some code whenever a class is subclassed. For that, one just has to override the `__init_subclass__` method.

However, it seems that cython 0.29 does not support `__init_subclass__` method for extension types. Instead, I use the `__subclasses__` method (which only tracks direct subclasses) as follows:

```py
cdef class A:

    @classmethod
    def subclasses(cls) -> dict:
        subclasses = {}

        for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
            subclasses[subclass.__name__] = subclass
            subclasses |= subclass.get_subclasses()

        return subclasses
```

Comment: I don't think `__init_subclass__` is supported for extension types (i.e. `cdef classes`) on any version of Cython. That was my initial thought, but when I looked it was specifically an error. Using `__subclasses__` seems like the best solution